# Send SPL-tokens to unfunded account + set fee payer

Tags: spl-token, token, rent, jupiter

I'm trying to create a seamless process for my clients via paying for the transaction fees when initiating a tokenswap (token A to token B) via jupiter.

In this scenario, the user doesn't have any sol in their account or an ATA for token B. However, the user has 5 token A for example. In the code, I've set the fee payer to be SOME_FEE_PAYER which has more than enough SOL to execute the needed instructions but I'm running into some issues.

My goal is that the user can transfer from token A to token B without paying any gas fees. For some reason, there doesn't seem to be an issue when I ran it in another test case where the user is rent-exempt + has an ATA for token B (i.e. transaction fee is actually paid by SOME_FEE_PAYER).

Back end

```
const {
      computeBudgetInstructions,
      setupInstructions: setupInstructionPayload, // Setup missing ATA for the users.
      swapInstruction: swapInstructionPayload, // The actual swap instruction.
      addressLookupTableAddresses, // The lookup table addresses that you can use if you are using versioned transaction.
    } = (
      await axios.post("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap-instructions", {
        quoteResponse: config.route,
        userPublicKey: config.sourceWalletAddress,
        wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
      })
    ).data;

let setupInstruction: any;
// Create user ata if needed 
if (setupInstructionPayload) {
  setupInstruction = new solana.TransactionInstruction({
    programId: new solana.PublicKey(setupInstructionPayload[0].programId),
    keys: setupInstructionPayload[0].accounts.map((key: any) => ({
      pubkey: new solana.PublicKey(key.pubkey),
      isSigner: key.isSigner,
      isWritable: key.isWritable,
    })),
    data: Buffer.from(setupInstructionPayload[0].data, "base64"),
  });
  console.log(setupInstruction);
}
const swapInstruction = new solana.TransactionInstruction({
  programId: new solana.PublicKey(swapInstructionPayload.programId),
  keys: swapInstructionPayload.accounts.map((key: any) => ({
    pubkey: new solana.PublicKey(key.pubkey),
    isSigner: key.isSigner,
    isWritable: key.isWritable,
  })),
  data: Buffer.from(swapInstructionPayload.data, "base64"),
});

const connection = solanaConnection();
const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const lookupTableAccount = await connection.getAddressLookupTable(new solana.PublicKey(addressLookupTableAddresses[0])).then((res) => res.value);

const ix = setupInstruction ? [setupInstruction, swapInstruction] : [swapInstruction];
console.log(ix);

console.log("pubkey\n", new solana.PublicKey(config.sourceWalletAddress), "\nblockhash\n", blockhash.blockhash, "\ninstruction\n", ix, "\nlookuptableaccount\n", [
  lookupTableAccount as solana.AddressLookupTableAccount,
]);

const messageV0 = new solana.TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: new solana.PublicKey(process.env.SOLANA_RELAYER_PUBLIC_ADDRESS!),
  recentBlockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
  instructions: ix,
}).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount as solana.AddressLookupTableAccount]);

const transaction = new solana.VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
const serializedTransaction = Buffer.from(transaction.serialize()).toString("base64");
return serializedTransaction;
```

Front end

```
const transaction = solana.VersionedTransaction.deserialize(Buffer.from(serializedTransaction, "base64"));
  const block = await solanaConnection().getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.message.recentBlockhash = block.blockhash;

  const sourceWallet = solana.Keypair.fromSecretKey(base58.decode(sourceWalletSecret));
  const solanaRelayerKp = solana.Keypair.fromSecretKey(base58.decode(process.env.SOLANA_RELAYER_PRIVATE_KEY!));
  transaction.sign([solanaRelayerKp, sourceWallet]);
  const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
  const signature = await solanaConnection().sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
    maxRetries: 5,
  });
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What happens to an unfunded account with spl-tokens sent to them? i.e. issues pertaining to rent
2. When I run this code, I get

```
failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1 (insufficient balance error)
```

on line

```
const signature = await solanaConnection().sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
```

even though I've double checked that SOME_FEE_PAYER_KEY has more than sufficient SOL (approximately 1 SOL). Is there something I'm missing?

(Edit)
Here's the print out statement

For setupInstructionPayload:

```
[
      {
        programId: 'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL',
        accounts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
        data: 'AQ=='
      }
]
```

For setupInstruction

```
TransactionInstruction {
      keys: [
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(B5CNx3z2p1mWrThmJfVmudhd2iDSA16Yi1Sj1v1rGcvs)]],
          isSigner: true,
          isWritable: true
        },
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(4M7uY5XZkUHCZAXp2LvT5jp3Ak5zXmBBoiLZ4CsHLgVN)]],
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: true
        },
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(B5CNx3z2p1mWrThmJfVmudhd2iDSA16Yi1Sj1v1rGcvs)]],
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: false
        },
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v)]],
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: false
        },
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(11111111111111111111111111111111)]],
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: false
        },
        {
          pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)]],
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: false
        }
      ],
      programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL)] {
        _bn: <BN: 8c97258f4e2489f1bb3d1029148e0d830b5a1399daff1084048e7bd8dbe9f859>
      },
      data: <Buffer 01>
    }
```

where B5CNx3z2p1mWrThmJfVmudhd2iDSA16Yi1Sj1v1rGcvs is the user pubkey

Comment: Can you please show me the code for the setupInstruction?

Comment: @DoublersKay Yep added it in the post